# what should I do If I want to do nothing in the one of my execution path in Background trigger cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

as far as I know, background trigger cloud function should return a promise,right? but what if I want to do nothing in the one of my execution path ?

```
export const updateDataWhenUserUnattendTheEvent = functions.firestore
    .document('events/{eventId}/Attendee/{userId}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {

        const eventID = context.params.eventId
        const eventRef = snap.ref.firestore.collection('events').doc(eventID)
        const db = admin.firestore()

        return db.runTransaction(async t => {
            const doc = await t.get(eventRef)

            if (doc) {

                const eventRankPoint = doc.data().rankPoint
                let eventCapacity = doc.data().capacity 

                return t.update(eventRef,{
                    isFullCapacity : false,
                    capacity : eventCapacity + 1,
                    rankPoint: eventRankPoint - 1
                })

            } else {

                // what should I write in here? empty promise?


                return new Promise()

            }




        })


    })
```

I want to my function worked only if the document is exist. so what should I do ? I write new Promise but .... I don't know what to do actually. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just return `null` if there's no asynchronous work to perform in some code path of your functions.  You only truly need a promise if it tracks some async work.

Alternatively, you could return a promise that's resolved immediately with [`Promise.resolve(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Answer (score 0):

Because `db.runTransaction` is an `async` function it will return a `Promise` all the time.

You can drop the `else` statement and the method will perform as expected because `runTransaction` will return `Promise<void>` which is a valid response for Cloud Functions

```js
export const updateDataWhenUserUnattendTheEvent = functions.firestore
    .document('events/{eventId}/Attendee/{userId}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
        const eventID = context.params.eventId;
        const eventRef = snap.ref.firestore.collection('events').doc(eventID);
        const db = admin.firestore();

        return db.runTransaction(async t => {
            const doc = await t.get(eventRef);

            if (doc) {
                const eventRankPoint = doc.data().rankPoint;
                let eventCapacity = doc.data().capacity ;

                return t.update(eventRef,{
                    isFullCapacity : false,
                    capacity : eventCapacity + 1,
                    rankPoint: eventRankPoint - 1
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

You can also make the `onDelete` function `async` which means you can force it to always return a `Promise` - the below is valid and will exit the function correctly.

```js
  export const updateDataWhenUserUnattendTheEvent = functions.firestore
    .document('events/{eventId}/Attendee/{userId}')
    .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
        // Do Nothing

        return;
    });
```