# Returning null from firebase cloud function - background triggers

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using firebase cloud functions with background triggers, if there are no promises in pending state, Doug Stevenson suggests we return `null`. Here are 2 places where he suggests this:

https://youtu.be/7IkUgCLr5oA?t=120

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214464/188740

Is there any special treatment with `null` in cloud functions?

For example, all of these should terminate properly:

```
export const onFooWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('foos/{fooId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // do nothing (i.e. returns undefined)
  });


export const onFooWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('foos/{fooId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    return someAsyncFunction(); // returns a promise
  });

export const onFooWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('foos/{fooId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    if (something) return; // returns nothing (i.e. undefined)

    return someAsyncFunction(); // returns a promise
  });

export const onFooWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('foos/{fooId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    await someAsyncFunction();
    // returns nothing AFTER the promise is resolved
  });
```

I believe these are all fine, yet Doug Stevenson recommends returning `null` when we don't return a promise. Is there a special treatment for `null`?

Comment: [T = 140s](https://youtu.be/7IkUgCLr5oA?t=140) in same video - "If you return any other type of value (and not a Promise), Cloud function will ignore it and terminate the function". One might return some object but since they are background functions they are not being sent anywhere so maybe null seems to do the job.

Comment: @Dharmaraj doesn't that mean that we can return anything (not just `null`) and it would be the same thing? By extension, we can simply not return anything (which will be interpreted as returning `undefined`) and that should do the same, wouldn't it? So in other words, there's nothing special about null, right? Still looking for confirmation 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that you certainly have to follow Doug's advice and try to return `null`, this is one of the reasons [why event-driven functions fail to complete](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#why_event-driven_functions_fail_to_complete)

> When functions written in Node.js return a rejected promise or pass a non-null value to a callback.
>
> the function stops executing by default and the event is discarded.

You also need to [terminate your background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#terminating_background_functions) and return a null value or use another promise method.

> If a function creates background tasks (such as threads, futures, Node.js Promise objects, callbacks, or system processes), you must terminate or otherwise resolve these tasks before returning from your function. Any tasks that are not terminated prior to returning from a particular execution may not be completed, and may also cause undefined behavior.

Comment: BIngo! You nailed it. Can you elaborate on having to terminate background functions? I thought it was enough to return a promise and the execution will complete.

Comment: Visit the Tips & Tricks page, this [section](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#ensure_http_functions_send_an_http_response) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). Other than that, I think you should investigate more on your own about promises in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp) and even doing a quick internet search there is some very good information.

Comment: I understand now. By `terminating the background function`, you're referring to the background task (i.e async function that gets called from the main function) and not the main function itself. Often the main function is called a background function for listeners (e.g. `onCreate`, `onWrite`, etc), so just a terminology confusion.